# Why is this node js request returning 401 status code?

Tags: node.js, oauth, oauth-2.0, httprequest

This is a simple oauth2 request for an access token. Running this returns a 401 status code and a null error object. Passing the same parameters with a curl request completes successfully.

```
var request = require('request');
var payload = {
                "grant_type": "password",
                "client_id": user.clientID,
                "client_secret": user.clientsecret,
                "username": user.username,
                "password": user.password
              };

var options = {
                method: 'POST',
                url: baseURL + passrequestURL,
                headers: {
                           'accept': "application/json",
                           'content-type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                },
                data: JSON.stringify(payload)
              };

function callback(error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    var info = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log(info);
  } else {
    console.log(response.statusCode);
  }
}

request(options, callback);
```

Comment: I'd suggest you use a network sniffer to examine exactly what is being sent with your `request()` vs. when using curl.  If you're getting a different result, then something is likely different in the request.

Comment: agree with the previous comment, some of the `user.*` variables could be set differently or not at all

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Switched the "data" field to a "form" field and passed it the payload object without turning it into a JSON string.

I used the Postman chrome extension to figure this out and highly recommend it.